# Python plotting contour of function generated in for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I want to do a contour plot for a function `z` (its values are in `zlist`), where the axes show the parameters `x` and `y`. The `z` is produced inside two for loops where I specify different `x` and `y`. I get an error `TypeError: Input z must be a 2D array` when I run this. How can I manipulate `zlist` so that it is plottable?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def myfunction(x,y):
    c = x + 2*y
    z = c*x + 0.5*y
    return c,z

xlist = np.linspace(0,1,10)
ylist = np.linspace(0,10,20)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(xlist,ylist)

zlist = []

for x in xlist:

    for y in ylist:

        z = myfunction(x,y)[1]
        zlist.append(z)

plt.figure()        
plt.contour(X,Y,zlist)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Instead of editing the question to include an answer, it's worth [answering your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) so that the question can be marked as answered. Also `_, Z = myfunction(X, Y)` is the more pythonic way to ignore the first output of a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice of chthonicdaemon,

```
X,Y = np.meshgrid(xlist,ylist)

_, Z = myfunction(X,Y)

plt.figure()        
plt.contour(X,Y,Z)

plt.show()
```